# Sqlite Sort by time not working

Tags: android, sqlite, sorting, datetime, android-sqlite

I am storing date format  in sqlite table, I want sort by date from table.

Every record in my SQLite database contains a column which contains a date stored as a string in the format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'.

I am sharing my table structure. I am using this query to **sort by datetime** it not sorting by time but sort by date is working fine.

```
select * 
from messages_table 
where id = '444' 
order by datetime(date_time) asc
```

I am storing `datetime` as string in my below table

[image]

and I am getting the below wrong sorting by time output please see my date_time column in the picture, anyone guide me.

[image]

Comment: Can't understand this. On the first screenshot you have a table sorted by `date_time` in descending order, on the second - the same in accending order. What do you want exactly? Maybe you are confusing `ASC` and `DESC`?

Comment: I want to sort by date time with accending order, my query is not sorting by time

Comment: Why do you `order by datetime(date_time)` but not simply `order by date_time`?

Comment: I have tried this, but it is not sorting by time ,

Comment: Are you trying to say that 2017-10-30 01:33:35 should be lower in the list than any of the 2017-10-30 10:.... as 01:35:55 is 1:35:55pm? If so then you would need to have date_time be in 24 hour format or include AM/PM indicator.

Comment: What particular rows are sorted not how you want it? Why?

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem with the `TIME` datatype.

If I enter time values correctly, such as `8:00` or `13:00`, they are sorted as strings in an `ORDER BY` clause, in effect as `"800"` and `"1300"`, where the string `"1300"` is sorted before `"800"` in ascending order.

One solution is to pad all times with a leading `0`, so we get `"0800"` and `"1300"` which will be sorted time wise correctly.